# Is there a way to ignore warnings in dependent packages? Is there a way to #if an os that the compiler doesn't know about?

Tags: swift, compiler-warnings, swift-playground, preprocessor-directive, ipad-playgrounds

I am using Swift Playgrounds to do App Development.  One of my dependencies has some code like this:

```
#if os(visionOS)
```

That causes my app to have a warning due to Swift Playgrounds not being updated to Swift 5.9 and thus it doesn't know about visionOS.

The dependency is an open project so I could do a pull request, but is there a way to do a `#if` check for an OS that the compiler doesn't know about?  Perhaps there's a way to define the OS temporarily to silence the warning?

Comment: `#if os(visionOS)` can be wrapped in Swift version check: `#if swift(>=5.9)`

Comment: RTX, if you want to do that as an answer I'll mark it as solved.  That's a great solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this Swift version check to use `os(visionOS)`:

```swift
#if swift(>=5.9)
  #if os(visionOS)
    // Do Stuff Here
  #endif // os(visionOS)
#endif // swift(>=5.9)
```